# Uncaught ReferenceError: get is not defined rkt query redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to run simple api slice using rkt query of redux toolkit, but i always get this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: get is not defined, not sure if it's a bug, or something i do wrong

```
    import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const jokesApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'jokesApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
      baseUrl: 'https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/jokes/',
    }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      getJokeByType: builder.query({
        query: (type) => `${type}/random`,
      }),
    }),
  });
  
  export const { useGetJokeByTypeQuery } = jokesApi;
```

my app.js

```
import {useGetJokeByTypeQuery } from './ApiSlice'

const App = () => {

  const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error
} = useGetJokeByTypeQuery('programming')

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={get}>click here</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: get is not defined
    at App (App.js:15:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
```

Comment: Where does the `get` come from? Didn't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your app is using a variable named `get`, but you have nowhere written any code that actually defines that variable:

```js
      <button onClick={get}>click here</button>
```